# Run docker daemon using specific cgroup mount

Tags: docker

Looking at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/

I couldn't find an option to allow me to select specific **cgroup mount**.

For example, if we have `/sys/fs/cgroup/containers`, then we need *docker daemon* to use this as mount point for any container(s) we create. Any ideas?

Comment: it seems version 1.10.10 introduced --cgroup-parent option on daemon to set cgroup parent for all containers